# JavaScript infinite loops and Heap memory limit - fatal error: reached heap limit allocation failed - javascript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, performance, heap-memory

I am trying to run some scripts that require a loop to run indefinitely (until a certain condition is met but this could take forever). The operations within the loop are very simple and do not create new variables, push elements to arrays or make new calls. Basically, no new resources are used on every loop, at least as far as I see it. However, I end up getting the infamous error:

```
fatal error: reached heap limit allocation failed - javascript heap out of memory
```

I have been investigating memory usage in loops and for the sake of simplicity of my question, mine can be considered analogue to this:

```
async function main(){
    let n = 5;
    while(1){
        console.log("number: " + n + "; squared: " + n**2);
        console.log(process.memoryUsage());
    }    
}
```

I found that the heap usage keeps growing on every loop despite "nothing" being made. I tried this same **turning the loop into a recursive function** with similar results. I am also familiar with changing the heap memory size allocation but that is not a solution for this case since I need this to run indefinitely.

What coding formulation should I use to run a loop like this? What should I change to make this possible without the heap growing? I know a bit about the **garbage collector** and I can figure it is this feature what is causing the limitation but cannot really understand why. This thing I want to do seems to me a pretty straightforward need that many other people will have come across with and I cannot believe Java has just disabled it like this.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: This is a JavaScript issue, has nothing to do with Java. Correcting the tag.

Comment: The solution really depends exactly what is happening. The while loop without an ending is not going to be a solution.

Comment: Well, then consider it not to be endless but iterating several million times. The actual problem would be the same.

Comment: There is ways to iterate large loops. setInterval, setTimeout, requestAnimationFrame, web workers, etc. best solution really depends on what you are doing.

Comment: 1. Java is not Javascript and both the title and body of your question confuse the two. 2. `process` is not available in a browser, but you did not tag this question node.js. Please update the question.

Comment: *despite "nothing" being made* -- Your loop allocates a new string.

Comment: ...and a number for the heap memory usage, which will get exponentially larger each iteration of the loop (the number gets allocated on the heap, and will be a bigger number each iteration)...which is probably the source of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to use setInterval or requestAnimationFrame. JavaScript is single-threaded, which may cause infinite loops (even in async functions) to potentially block the execution of other code.

I hope this will fix your issue.

```
let n = 5;

function someFunction() {
  console.log("number: " + n + "; squared: " + n ** 2);
  console.log(process.memoryUsage());
}

someFunction();
setInterval(performTask, 1000);
```

Comment: Could you please ellaborate on how `setInterval` would mitigate this situation? In many other questions it is shown as a source of memory leakage, as a matter of fact. Would `setTimeout` be valid for this purpose, too?

Comment: The main reason is that setInterval will cause another async method to be called as opposed to the while true which will keep looping forever and increasing the heap size.

setTimeout is only called once. This is unless you want to call it by the end of the function everytime, which is also fine. 

requestAnimationFrame is also another alternative as I mentioned earlier.